# Limit $\lim_{n→∞}\frac1n\sum_{j=c_n}^n\frac1{2n-2j+1}\sum_{k=1}^jk\prod_{i=k}^{j-1}\frac{2n-2i}{2n-2i+1}. $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

If $c_n/n\to c>0$ as $n\to\infty$ (At the beginning of this question, I though the assumption is $c_n\to c$. With the help of [metamorphy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/543769/metamorphy), the question will be ill-posed. So, the assumption has changed to the current one.), I would like to find$$\lim_{n→∞}\frac1n\sum_{j=c_n}^n\frac1{2n-2j+1}\sum_{k=1}^jk\prod_{i=k}^{j-1}\frac{2n-2i}{2n-2i+1}.
$$

Let $A_n=\sum_{j=c_n}^n\frac1{2n-2j+1}\sum_{k=1}^jk\prod_{i=k}^{j-1}\frac{2n-2i}{2n-2i+1}$. Noting that 
$$
\prod_{i=k}^{j-1}\frac{2n-2i}{2n-2i+1}=\frac{2n-2j+1}{2n-2k+1}\frac{(-1)^{n-j}{-1/2\choose n-j}}{(-1)^{n-k}{-1/2\choose n-k}}, 
$$
we have
\begin{align*}
&A_n\\
=&\sum_{j=c_n}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\frac{k(-1)^{n-j}{-1/2\choose n-j}}{(2n-2k+1)(-1)^{n-k}{-1/2\choose n-k}}\\
=&\sum_{k=1}^{c_n-1}\sum_{j=c_n}^{n}\frac{k(-1)^{n-j}{-1/2\choose n-j}}{(2n-2k+1)(-1)^{n-k}{-1/2\choose n-k}}+\sum_{k=c_n}^{n}\sum_{j=k}^{n}\frac{k(-1)^{n-j}{-1/2\choose n-j}}{(2n-2k+1)(-1)^{n-k}{-1/2\choose n-k}}\\
=&\sum_{k=1}^{c_n-1}\frac{k}{(2n-2k+1)(-1)^{n-k}{-1/2\choose n-k}}\sum_{j=c_n}^{n}(-1)^{n-j}{-1/2\choose n-j}+\sum_{k=c_n}^{n}\frac{k}{(2n-2k+1)(-1)^{n-k}{-1/2\choose n-k}}\sum_{j=k}^{n}(-1)^{n-j}{-1/2\choose n-j}\\
=&\sum_{k=n-c_n+1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{(2k+1)(-1)^{k}{-1/2\choose k}}\sum_{j=0}^{n-c_n}(-1)^{j}{-1/2\choose j}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-c_n}\frac{n-k}{(2k+1)(-1)^{k}{-1/2\choose k}}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{j}{-1/2\choose j}\\
=&\sum_{k=n-c_n+1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{(2k+1)(-1)^{k}{-1/2\choose k}}(2n-2c_n+1)(-1)^{n-c_n}{-1/2\choose n-c_n}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-c_n}\frac{n-k}{(2k+1)(-1)^{k}{-1/2\choose k}}(2k+1)(-1)^{k}{-1/2\choose k}\\
=&(-1)^{n-c_n}(2n-2c_n+1){-1/2\choose n-c_n}\sum_{k=n-c_n+1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{(2k+1)(-1)^{k}{-1/2\choose k}}+\frac{n(n+1)-c_n(c_n-1)}{2},
\end{align*}
where the third-to-last equality follows since $\sum_{u=0}^{a}(-1)^{u}{-1/2\choose u}=(-1)^{a}(2a+1){-1/2\choose a}$.

Is it possible to give a further closed form of $A_n$? And find the limit of $A_n/n$ (expresses it in terms of $c$)? Please give me some help. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: I don't know how to deal with the product term. I really need your proof, please. Thank you very much.

Comment: By some simple algebra, I found that $\prod_{i=k}^{j-1}\frac{2n-2i}{2n-2i+1}=\frac{2n-2j+1}{2n-2k+1}2^{2(j-k)}\frac{{2n-2j\choose n-j}}{{2n-2k\choose n-k}}$. But, I still cannot obtain (n+1)/2 as you got.

Comment: Ready. See my answer.

Comment: Many thanks. You are very good at dealing with these things.

Comment: The new version must have $\frac{1}{n^2}$ in place of $\frac{1}{n}$ for the limit to exist. I'm still analysing it...

Comment: I very much appreciate your help. This is just one term in my problem. I have tried to investigate the problem in a different approach and may cause a different task to tackle, hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[outdated, should be unaccepted and deleted]

Comment: I haven't learned double factorial before. You are really good at this technique!!! I learned from you. Thanks.

Comment: I made a mistake that the assumption should be $c_n/n\to c$ as $n\to\infty$. In this case, $A_n$ seems not to have a closed form.

Comment: I have added a few sentences to thank your help.

Answer (score 0):

Now we assume that $c_n\to c$ as $n\to\infty$. I am not familiar with double factorial, but I tried to follow your approach (using the identify ${{2k\choose k}}/2^{2k}=(-1)^{k}{{-1/2\choose k}}$ implying that
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=k}^{j-1}\frac{2n-2i}{2n-2i+1}&=\frac{2n-2j+1}{2n-2k+1}2^{2(j-k)}\frac{{2n-2j\choose n-j}}{{2n-2k\choose n-k}}\\
&=\frac{2n-2j+1}{2n-2k+1}\frac{(-1)^{n-j}{{-1/2\choose n-j}}}{(-1)^{n-k}{{-1/2\choose n-k}}}
\end{align*}
) 
and I obtained that (by switching the summations and changing the variables)
$A_n=\alpha_n+\beta_n$ where
$$
\alpha_n=\frac{(-1)^{n-c_n}(2n-2c_n+1){{-1/2\choose n-c_n}}}{n}\sum_{k=n-c_n+1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{(2k+1)(-1)^{k}{{-1/2\choose k}}}
$$
and
$$
\beta_n=\frac{n(n+1)-c_n(c_n-1)}{2n}.
$$

Is it possible to simplify $A_n$ further so as to find the limit?

Comment: I suggest you to *amend* the question (rather than post it as an "answer"). And, of course, I'll look at that (since I called the original formulation "ill-posed", I expected some adjustments to appear).